# How to repeat same element in HTML without including them over and over?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working with Angular v11.0.4 and TypeScript.
The idea is to show between one and eight [progress spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples) which represent different stock storages with different values.
The storages can be empty so I would like to show **only the ones which actually have something inside**, therefore I'm looking for someway to do that without repeating the same HTML code eight times.

This is the element I want to repeat.

```
<div class="col-sm">
      <label><strong>Storage X:</strong></label>
      <mat-progress-spinner
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          [mode]="mode"
          [value]="value">
      </mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>
```

If you have any idea or advise I'll appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: This is why we have ngFor https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described as a comment, the best way to not duplicate code, is to use `*ngFor` ([Angular documation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)) and specify in your component what the values should be.

Here's a quick setup that should keep you moving.

#### Component.html

Add `*ngFor="let progress of progressItems"` to the surrounding `div`. It will now loop through all of the items that are in the component's defined array.

```html
<div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let progress of progressItems">
    <label><strong>Storage X:</strong></label>
    <mat-progress-spinner class="example-margin" [color]="progress.color" [value]="progress.value" mode="determinate">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
</div>
```

#### Component.ts

Define `progressItems` in your component, and give it values that belong to your needs (these are just random values for demonstration purposes only).

```js
progressItems: progress[] = [
    {
      color: "primary",
      value: 50
    },
    {
      color: "accent",
      value: 20
    },
    {
      color: "primary",
      value: 80
    },
    {
      color: "warn",
      value: 95
    }
  ];
```

Since it's TypeScript and to make it more safe, I added a type of `progress` to it and declared that interface as well.

```js
interface progress {
  color: string;
  value: number;
}
```

[image: Example of progress spinners]

Two things to mention: do no not forget to import `MatProgressSpinnerModule` into your app's module and also add a Material theme to the CSS file, like below to see it actually working.

```css
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

See [this working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d5wfee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for the overview of the steps we just did.